# How to draw a circular diagram and label the radius and label other parts

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hi I want to draw this in overleaf and have got this so far and not sure how to label it. I wanted to label the radius and difference between the two radii of the circles which is supposed to be 1.5

This is what I have so far.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray] (0,0) circle (2cm) (0:3) arc (0:-360:3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Like this?

**Edit:**
Now added a dot at circles origins

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Straight Barb,
lbl/.style = {font=\small, above, sloped}
                        ]
\draw[fill=gray!30] (0,0) coordinate (O)  circle[radius=3.5cm];
\draw[fill=white]       (O) circle[radius=2cm];
\fill                   (O) circle[radius=2pt];
\draw[|<->|, semithick] (0:2) -- node[lbl] {$\qty{1.5}{\meter}$} ++ (0:1.5);
   \draw[->, semithick] (O) -- node[lbl] {$r$} ++ (60:2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: please, always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document`, as is done above!

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much! And also, I see the note and will do that. Thanks again.

Comment: @user292225, you are welcome! BTW, you can accept answer )by clicking on the checl mark at top left side of answer).  ;-)